# Expected '(' or '[' when creating ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, gridworld

I am making a program that uses GridWorld for Java.  I want to use an ArrayList in my code but JGrasp is giving me a very strange error that is very infuriating.  This is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Actor> getActors()
{
     ArrayList <Location> occLocs = getGrid().getOccupiedLocations();
     ArrayList <Actor> a = new ArrayList <Actor>;

     for(Location test: occLocs)
     {
        a.add(getGrid().get(test));
     }

     return a;
}
```

And this is the error that I got:

```
AttractiveCritter.java:12: error: '(' or '[' expected
     ArrayList <Actor> a = new ArrayList <Actor>;
```

Comment: Check your syntax.  In the class instance creation expressions to be exact.

Comment: Typo: `ArrayList <Actor> a = new ArrayList <Actor>();`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing open and closed parentheses needed when creating an object. Change,

```
ArrayList <Actor> a = new ArrayList <Actor>;
```

to

```
ArrayList <Actor> a = new ArrayList <Actor>();
```

and your error should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Stupid error on my part.